# SocketIO send event withargs?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, networking, socket.io

I'm kind of new to this with network programming. I'm trying to write a server right now. On the server side I have a method:

```
   socket.on("joinserver", function(name, device) {
});
```

On the client side I've using socket.io for Objective C. I've a little experience with java         script. but from what i've hard arguments are similar to an array. And seems to be no function like sendEvent: withArray: nor sendevent: with args:. So is there any way that I can send a event "join server" with the two arguments name and device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

On server:

```
socket.on("joinserver", function(data) {
     var name=data.name;
     var device=data.device;
});
```

On client side(in javascript):

```
var inp={
    device:"Device",
    name:"Name"
}
socket.emit("joinserver",inp);
```